# PySimpleGui How to update a column?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

My problem is that pysymplegui doesnt wants to update my column, i tried the window.refesh() and some other commands but nothing seems to work. When i try to update a sg.text it works. I guess it's a coding mistake i made, maybe someone can find it ( :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
column1 = [
    [sg.Text(f'Scrollable{i}')] for i in range(10)
]

layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(column1, key='key1'),
        sg.Button(key='button1'),

    ]
]

window = sg.Window('Scrollable', layout, finalize=True)

def change():
    column3 = [
        [sg.Text(f'Test{i}')] for i in range(10)
    ]
    window['key1'].update(column3)
    window.refresh()


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'button1':
        change()
```

Comment: Without really understanding what you are trying to do, it looks like the variable ```column3``` is local the the function ```change```  For this reason the command ```window['key1'].update(column3)``` doesn't have any effect

Comment: The layout cannot be updated by method `update`, it work only for some attributes of the element, like `visible` for the Column element. Refer the section for call reference about PySimpleGUI.

Comment: @JasonYang So there is no way i can get a update for an column?

Comment: You can do it by put lot of Column elements at same row, but only one Column element with visible=True. To update to which Column element, update only it with visible=True.

Answer (score 2):

BIG SHOUTOUT TO Jason and Mike for all their work/help with PSG. I am where I am because of them.
This example expands on Jason's recommendation to use visible for the Column element.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
column1 = [[sg.Text(f'Scrollable{i}')] for i in range(10)]
column3 = [[sg.Text(f'Test{i}')] for i in range(10)]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(column1, key='key1', visible=True),sg.Column(column3, key='key3', visible=False),
     sg.Button(key='button1'),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window('Scrollable', layout, finalize=True)

flipper = True
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'button1':
        if flipper:
            window['key1'].Update(visible=False)
            window['key3'].Update(visible=True)
            # window.refresh()
            flipper = False
        elif not flipper:
            window['key1'].Update(visible=True)
            window['key3'].Update(visible=False)
            # window.refresh()
            flipper = True
        
    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Comment: `window.refresh()` is not necessary here because next statement `window.read()` will refresh the GUI. The Button without button_text will be a small block, and it is included at same row as those Column elements, the order of elements will be changed after hide and unhide.

Comment:  very nice Macs.... there's a trinket in the [eCookbook](https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/layouts/swapping-window-layouts) that may be of help too.